# How to perform undo action in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, undo

I have tried to perform "undo" action but actually it was working once in editor mode . Also it was not working on a device. I want to track the object position, rotation and enabling/disabling `gameObject` . Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use Memento pattern for that task : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18025/Generic-Memento-Pattern-for-Undo-Redo-in-C

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what about store in a list your actions? it allways works for me ^^

Comment: You can Create `Stack<Data>` and **class** that **store the data** that you need. **push(save) data to Stack** at any point and pop(restore) it if required. for saving data you can convert stack to an array and use `JsonUtility` and save on a file and repopulate the stack at `Awake`. This can be use for `TimeShift` effect too.

Answer (score 0):

The class **PreviousState** represents information about the previous state of the object and provides methods to undo any changes. The class **PreviousStateStack** contains these objects.
In user code:

- Instantiate **PreviousState** each time your program makes any changes.
- Fill the **PreviousState** properties:

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **Obj** | Changed object. |
| **Value** | Object value before changing. |
| **Action** | Delegate that contains instructions for restore value. It usually sets **PreviousState.Value** to the object and moves the focus to the changed GUI component. By default it just sets **Value** to **Obj**. |

- Next step push created **PreviousState** in the **PreviousStateStack**.
- Pop it when need undo changes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or "Undo" button is pressed) and run the **PreviousState.Action**.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace System
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Encapsulates a method that restores the previous state of an object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">Managed object to restore to previous value.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The previous state of the managed object.</param>
    public delegate void RestoreAction(ref object obj, object value, params object[] parameters);

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the implementation of <see cref="Stack{T}"/> for storage and retrieval
    /// previous state of managed objects.
    /// </summary>
    public class PreviousStateStack : Stack<IEnumerable<PreviousState>>, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<PreviousState>>
    {
        private const int DEF_CAPACITY = 256;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance <see cref="PreviousStateStack"/>
        /// with initial capacity <see cref="DEF_CAPACITY"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public PreviousStateStack() : base(DEF_CAPACITY)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance <see cref="PreviousStateStack"/>
        /// with initial capacity <paramref name="capacity"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="capacity">Initial number of elements.</param>
        public PreviousStateStack(int capacity) : base(capacity)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance <see cref="PreviousStateStack"/>
        /// with the specified stack item by the <paramref name="items"/> parameter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">Objects <see cref="PreviousState"/> to be inserted into <see cref="Stack{T}" />.</param>
        public PreviousStateStack(params PreviousState[] items) : base(DEF_CAPACITY)
        {
            push(items);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Restores the previous state of the managed object,
        /// represented by this instance <see cref="PreviousState"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public void Restore()
        {
            var states = Pop();
            foreach (var state in states) state.Restore();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts the enumerated objects <see cref="PreviousState"/> as the top element of the stack <see cref="Stack{T}" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">
        /// Objects <see cref="PreviousState"/> to be inserted into <see cref="Stack{T}" />.
        /// </param>
        public void Push(params PreviousState[] items)
        {
            Push((IEnumerable<PreviousState>)items);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides information about the previous state of managed objects.
    /// </summary>
    [SecurityCritical]
    public sealed class PreviousState
    {
        private IntPtr _objPtr;

        private static void DefaultAction(ref object obj, object value, params object[] parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                var reference = __makeref(obj);
                __refvalue(reference, object) = value;
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines an action that allows you to restore the previous state of the managed object.
        /// </summary>
        public RestoreAction Action { get; } = DefaultAction;

        /// <summary>
        /// Managed object for which to store the previous value.
        /// </summary>
        public object Obj
        {
            get
            {
                var handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(_objPtr);
                return handle.Target;
            }
            private set
            {
                var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(value);
                _objPtr = (IntPtr) handle;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores the previous value of the managed object.
        /// </summary>
        public object Value { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance <see cref="PreviousState"/>
        /// for the specified managed object and its previous state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Object for which the previous state will be saved.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The previous state of the object.</param>
        public PreviousState(object obj, object value)
        {
            obj=obj?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
            Value = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance <see cref="PreviousState"/>
        /// for the specified managed object, its previous state, and the action by which
        /// it will be restored.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Object for which the previous state will be saved.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The previous state of the object.</param>
        /// <param name="action">An action that allows you to restore the previous state of the object.</param>
        public PreviousState(object obj, object value, RestoreAction action) : this(obj, value)
        {
            Action = action?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Restores the previous state of the managed object,
        /// represented by this instance <see cref="PreviousState"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public void Restore()
        {
            objectobj = obj;
            Action?.Invoke(ref obj, this.Value);
        }
    }
}
```